# How to calculate the distribution of $2W(1.5) - W(2)$ where $W(t)$ is the Wiener process?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, wiener-measure

Suppose $W(t)$ is a Wiener process (which satisfies the following properties):

1. $W(0)=0$
2. $W(T) - W(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, T-t)$ for any $t<T$
3. For any $0<t_{1}<...t_{j}<....<t_{n}$, increments $W(t_{j})$, $W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_{j})$ are independent random variables.

I would like to find the distribution of $2W(1.5) - W(2)$ and I am getting conflicting answers.

*My first method.* Since $W(1.5) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1.5)$, then we know that $2W(1.5) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 6)$ using the fact that for any random variable $X$, the expectation and variance of $2X$ are respectively $E(2X) = 2E(X)$ and $Var(2X) = 4Var(X)$ . Thus, we have:

$$2W(1.5) - W(2) = W(6) - W(2) = W(4) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,4)$$ using property 2 above.

*My second method*. Let $Y = W(1.5) - (W(2) - W(1.5))$. Then $W(1.5) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1.5)$, $W(2) - W(1.5) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 0.5)$ and these are independent, hence the difference $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$.

(My last step is using standard fact that if two random variables, say $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$, are independent, then $E(X_{1}-X_{2}) = E(X_{1}) - E(X_{2})$ and $Var(X_{1} - X_{2}) = Var(X_{1}) + Var(X_{2})$ ).

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear combination of Gaussian variables is normally distributed. It remains to calculate mean and variance. Let $s<t$. $E[aW_s-W_t]=aE[W_s]-E[W_t]=0$. For the variance
$$V[aW_s-W_t]=a^2V[W_s]+V[W_t]-2a\textrm{Cov}(W_s,W_t)$$
By definition, $V[W_s]=s,V[W_t]=t$. Now we calculate the covariance. Since the means are zero:
$$\begin{aligned}\textrm{Cov}(W_s,W_t)&=E[W_tW_s]=\\
&=E[((W_t-W_s)+W_s)W_s]=\\
&=E[(W_t-W_s)W_s]+E[W_s^2]=\\
&=E[W_t-W_s]E[W_s]+s=s\end{aligned}$$
So
$$aW_s-W_t\sim \mathcal{N}(0,a^2s+t-2as)$$

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer @Snoop